# How can I pass a date to a sql file when executing a query in Airflow

Tags: sql, airflow

I am using BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator in airflow. I have my sql in a separate file, and I am passing params to that file, specifically I am passing folder names and dates. When I pass a date though, I get an error, because the date is passed into the sql file without any 'quotes'.

Error
400 No matching signature for function DATE for argument types

From Airflow Logs. The param is sent to the sql file with no 'quotes' around it
DATE(2020-01-01)

Ways I have tried to define the date

```
   partitionFilter = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   partitionFilter = str(datetime.today()).split()[0]
   partitionFilter = '2020-01-01'
   partitionFilter = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Fixed that seems to work
In the sql file, if I wrap the passed param in 'quotes', sql is able to read it is a date. This seems a little hacky, and I am wondering is there a better way. What I am concerned with is that as this application grows, maybe the date will be passed a different way and it will include 'quotes', which would not work since the 'quotes' are hard coded in the sql file.
This works in the sql file if I wrap param in 'quotes':

```
DATE('{{params.partitionFilter}}')
```

This does not work in the sql file:

```
DATE( {{params.partitionFilter}} )
```

excerpt from Dag

```
partitionFilter = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

with DAG(
    dag_id,
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    start_date= days_ago(1),
    catchup = False,
    user_defined_macros={"DATASET": DATASET_NAME,}
) as dag:

    query_one = BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator(
        task_id='query_one',
        sql='/sql/my-file.sql',
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        params={'partitionFilter':partitionFilter}
    )
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what is the issue that you are facing. Can you please write the output SQL that you except to submit to BigQuery?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The issue I have is that when I pass dates to my sql file, I have to add quotes in the sql file for it to work. So my SQL is DATE('{{params.partitionFilter}}'), and params.partitionFilter is my date I am passing. Again this works, I just don't know why when I pass a date, the SQL makes me wrap it in quotes. If this is normal behavior, then I answered my own question, and the proper way to pass dates in airflow to a separate airflow file is to wrap the date in quotes.

Comment: please post an example of the format of the query you want to be submitted to BigQuery. As you say what you wrote works so it's very hard to understand what is the issue you describe.